# WordPress ACF - вывод поля на всех страницах сайта

Tags: wordpress, acf

WordPress ACF - нужно чтоб произвольное поле выводилось на всех страницах сайта (например в футере) Как это сделать?

Comment: Если для футера или хедера, то лучше создавать в кастомайзере или добавлять поля в разделе настроек, acf лучше для постов или страниц использовать, хотя он тоже позволяет создавать страницы с опциями. Ну и соответственно нужно понимать, что там будет выводиться, статический контент или на каких-то страницах будет отличаться.

Comment: Давайте я сформулирую вопрос по другому: мне нужно чтобы блоки в футере можно было изменять в админке (и не через редактор шаблона footer.php), желательно в каких то полях. Как это возможно реализовать?

Comment: Чем вас виджеты не устраивают? Регистрируете сайдбар и выводите что угодно с помощью виджетов

Answer (score 2):

В ACF есть возможность создавать отдельную страницу [настроек](http://acfwp.ru/stranica-s-opciyami-options-page/). Но если такой вариант не устраивает, то можно создать нужные поля для главной страницы, а потом выводить их в нужном месте. В коде это выглядит так:

```php
//Получаем ID главной страницы
$front_id = get_option( 'page_on_front' );

//Получаем нужное поле
$field  = get_field( 'field_value', $front_id );
```